# What is a correct primitive hexagonal unit cell to describe a monolayer of molybdenum sulfide?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, molecular-structure

I searched the coordinates or reduced coordinates of primitive cell of mono layer hexagonal $\ce{MoS2}$, but there are lots of different structures and coordination. For example, [material project](https://materialsproject.org/materials/mp-2815/) give this:

\begin{array}{c|ccc} \hline
\textbf{Element} & a &b& c \\\hline
 \ce{Mo} &0.3333 &0.6667 &0.25 \\                  
 \ce{Mo} &0.6667 &0.3333 &0.75  \\                         
 \ce{S} &0.3333 &0.6667 &0.362 \\                     
 \ce{S} &0.3333 &0.6667 &0.138 \\               
 \ce{S} &0.6667 &0.3333 &0.638 \\            
 \ce{S} &0.6667 &0.3333 &0.862  \\  \hline
\end{array}

but there are another structures too, that is:

\begin{array}{c|ccc} \hline
\textbf{Element} & a &b& c \\\hline
\ce{Mo}&0.0 &0.0 &0.25 \\                      
 \ce{Mo}&0.0 &0.0 &0.75 \\                        
 \ce{S} &0.3333 &0.6667 &0.362 \\                        
 \ce{S} &0.3333 &0.6667 &0.138  \\                       
 \ce{S} &0.6667 &0.3333 &0.638 \\                          
 \ce{S} &0.6667 &0.3333 &0.862 \\  \hline                
\end{array}

and there more than these. So, which one is correct?

Answer (score 8):

Entries [mp-2815](https://materialsproject.org/materials/mp-2815/) and [mp-1018809](https://materialsproject.org/materials/mp-1018809/) differ in their lattice constants ($c = 14.879\ Å$ *vs.* $c = 13.983\ Å$) reported, thus differ in unit cell volume and density (4.05 g/cm³ *vs.* 4.31 g/cm³) while sharing the same space group symmetry $P6_3/mmc$.  But only the former is labeled as «stable», the later one is annotated with «Decomposes To $\ce{MoS2}$».  It is possible that the later entry is simply about a metastable polymorph.

About half-way through the pages by materials project you find the entry *Electronic Structure* with (in these cases) referrals to the [ICSD database](https://icsd.products.fiz-karlsruhe.de/).  Thanks to a collaboration with [CCDC](https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/), a sub-set of *some* data of the databases' corresponding entries, including bibliographic information, may be retrieved on their [joint web page](https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/structures/) by entering the ICSD entry number ([result 1](https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/structures/Search?Ccdcid=24000&DatabaseToSearch=ICSD), [result 2](https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/structures/Search?Ccdcid=644259&DatabaseToSearch=ICSD)).*

Indeed a search, e.g., on the [COD](https://www.crystallography.net/cod/) reveal that there are *at least* two experimentally characterized polymorphs of $\ce{MoS2}$ known where differences justify a description in different space group symmetries:

- $P 6_3/m m c$, $a = b\ \pu{ = 3.15 Å}$, $c\ \pu{= 12.3 Å}$, $\alpha = \beta = 90^\circ$, $\gamma = 120^\circ$, e.g., entry [COD 1010993](https://www.crystallography.net/cod/1010993.html).
- $R3m$, $a = b\ \pu{ = 3.163 Å}$, $c\ \pu{= 18.37 Å}$, $\alpha = \beta = 90^\circ$, $\gamma = 120^\circ$, e.g., entry [COD 9007661](https://www.crystallography.net/cod/9007661.html).

The $(a, b, c)$ of the lattice constants describe the unit cells' outer dimension.  They are not the *fractional* coordinates -- better described as $(x, y, z)$ -- to set the atoms position along these vectors.  (Which may [e.g., cubic Bravais class] orthogonal to each other, but need not to be [e.g., monoclinic Bravais class].)

*) Accessing the databases «for real», though, offers you a much easier comparison with other entries of either same chemical composition,  symmetry related space groups, similar unit cells, etc.

Comment: Is this true for a true **monolayer** (2D material) or does this answer only apply to bulk, 3D material. I see 3D unit cell volumes in those links which should be areas in 2D, and there should be no *c* axis. [1](https://www.ossila.com/pages/molybdenum-disulfide-mos2), [2](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-structure-of-single-layer-MoS2-a-The-top-view-a-hexagonal-lattice-structure-b_fig5_275054809), and [3](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2352847815000040). I think that the OP may have searched the wrong site if they really want to ask about 2D materials.

Comment: @uhoh I don't know for sure if the two entries the answer explicitly names are the two mentioned in the OP.  After all, some polymorphs are re-examined multiple times (e.g., different equipment, different experimental conditions of $T$, or / and $p$, etc.).  Nor did I read the two publications the two ICSD entries refer to. Thus it is not clear if these are about a bulk 3D crystal (and those examined in electron diffraction may be tiny, compared to conventional X-ray diffraction), or a 2D crystal.

Comment: @uhoh Depending on the line of thought, *true monolayer* may be understood differently, too. For self-organized monolayers of thiol-alkanes on Au, or LB films in general, the statement of your reference 1 «The crystal structure of *monolayer* MoS2 showing *a layer* of molybdenum atoms (blue) sandwiched *between two layers* of sulfur atoms (yellow).» already could be *conceptually two too many*, raising the question «why not a *more flat* (graphene like) material in first place?» as in e.g., in [c2db](https://cmr.fysik.dtu.dk/c2db/c2db.html) / [2dmatpedia.org](http://www.2dmatpedia.org/).